# Linear Diophantine Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was asked to find

i) all integer solutions, and

ii) all non-negative integer solutions

to the equations below. I know (a) has no answers, but have no idea how to go about proving the rest. Please help.

(a) $943x + 533y = 100000$

(b) $1249x + 379y = 5$

(c) $663x + 494y = 130$

Answer (score 0):

The equation $ax + by = n$ has integer solutions in $x, y$ if and only if the GCD of $a$ and $b$ divides $n$. Hence part (b) and part (c) does indeed have integer solutions, while part (a) indeed has none.

Make use of [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Non-uniqueness_of_solutions) (I'll leave the workings to you, so as to let you get a feel for this) to derive that the integer solutions for (b) is 
$$x = 379n + 220\\
y=-1249n - 725$$
 for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and that the integer solutions for (c) is 
$$x = 38n + 30\\
y= -51n - 40$$
for arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For part (ii), simply subject the solutions to the constraint that both $x,y$ must be non-negative, and observe that under this constraint, $n$ can admit only finitely many values, which gives you all of the non-negative integer solutions.